# pad not being added to uridecodebin

Tags: gstreamer

I'm currently working on a gstreamer pipeline that begins with a `uridecodebin` that opens a png file and that I hope to eventually link to an `imagefreeze` element (although in the future I may want to link it to any arbitrary element). I've connected to the `"pad-added"` signal, but it appears that `uridecodebin` doesn't ever actually create the pad.

After looking closely at the logs, it appears that it successfully opens the png file and links the `filesrc` to the `decodebin`, but there doesn't appear to be any pad created (the callback is never called, and when I iterate over the `src` pads of the `uridecodebin` after the file is opened, there are none). Does anyone know why this might be the case?

Unfortunately it's part of a much larger codebase so I can't share the full code but I can give excerpts of the relevant samples:

```
GstElement *uridecodebin = gst_element_factory_make ("uridecodebin", NULL);
GstElement *imagefreeze = gst_element_factory_make ("imagefreeze", NULL);
GstElement *sink = gst_element_factory_make ("fakesink", NULL);

g_object_set (G_OBJECT (uridecodebin), "uri"
    "file:///test.png", NULL);
g_signal_connect (uridecodebin, "pad-added",
    G_CALLBACK (uri_pad_added_cb), NULL);

gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (bin), uridecodebin, imagefreeze, sink, NULL);
gst_element_link (imagefreeze, sink);
```

And then, the callback (at this point, just a stub):

```
static void
uri_pad_added_cb (GstElement * element, GstPad * pad, gpointer data)
{
    GST_WARNING ("uri_pad_added_cb");
}
```